# What is channel_chat_created property of message type used for

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Message type has a channel_chat_created property. Does any one know in what situation this property will be available in message object?
We were hoping channel_chat_created is sent when an admin adds a bot to a channel but no notification is send when this happens.